# Filling a column with the current date each time the form is shown or loaded

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ms-access

I want to fill all the entries in a column with the current date so that I can compare it to a DateofTest column and determine how many days since the last test.  I think I can figure out the number of days but I can't figure out how to fill the column with the current date.

```
 Private Sub Reports_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
    mySql = "Update Studentdata, SET currentDate = Date()"
    ConnDB()
    myCommand = New OleDbCommand(mySql, myConnection)

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think you need the comma, try "Update Studentdata SET currentDate = Date()"

Comment: No luck.  It's weird because I don't get an error.  It just doesn't do anything to the column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you actually executing the update command?  Try this:

```
    Dim myConnection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection()  'Complete as needed
    Dim mySql As String = "Update Studentdata SET currentDate = Date()"
    Using cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(mySql, myConnection)
        Try
            cmd.Connection.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ERROR UPDATING")
        Finally
            cmd.Connection.Close()
        End Try
    End Using
```

or try populating the Date from your code and providing it as a parameter, like this:

```
     Using cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand()
        cmd.Connection = myConnection
        Try
            cmd.Connection.Open()
            cmd.CommandText = "Update Studentdata SET currentDate = @Date"
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Date", DateTime.Now))
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex1 As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex1.Message, "ERROR UPDATING")
        Finally
            cmd.Connection.Close()
        End Try
    End Using
```

Comment: That did the trick.  I added mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery() and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

As far a I remember access database can have some problems with dates that include miliseconds so you can do that (and remove the comma before "SET" also):

```
Dim dateWithoutMiliseconds as DateTime = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day)
mySql = String.Format("Update Studentdata SET currentDate = {0}", dateWithoutMiliseconds)
```